# Jenkins and docker-compose

Tags: jenkins, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to use docker-compose on a jenkins build. But I get :

```
docker-compose: not found
```

How I have to do for install docker-compose ? It's a plugin, or I have to modify the docker image of jenkins ?

I use jenkins:1.642.4

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install `docker-compose` first. This is the command:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.8.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

btw, this is the documentation:

```
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try, I was thinking that docker-compose was  packaged with composer.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a shell build step to invoke `docker-compose`, you will first need to install `docker-compose` on Jenkins master (or on a slave node) that runs your job. It is a stand-alone binary and detailed instructions to install it can be found [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/).

Comment: thank you for your answer, I will try, I was thinking that docker-compose was  packaged with composer.

Answer (score 0):

Gianmarco's answer worked for me. If you're installing Jenkins via Docker image (https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/), you can include the docker-compose installation as part of your image build. This way docker-compose becomes included with your deployable Jenkins image. Just add the CURL command to the Dockerfile:

```
FROM jenkins/jenkins:2.289.3-lts-jdk11  
USER root  
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apt-transport-https \  
       ca-certificates curl gnupg2 \  
       software-properties-common  
RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/debian/gpg | apt-key add -  
RUN apt-key fingerprint 0EBFCD88  
RUN add-apt-repository \  
       "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/debian \  
       $(lsb_release -cs) stable"  
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker-ce-cli  
RUN curl -L \  
  "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.25.3/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" \  
  -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose \  
  && chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose  
USER jenkins  
RUN jenkins-plugin-cli --plugins "blueocean:1.24.7 docker-workflow:1.26"
```